# ASP.Net check value with DBNULL

Tags: asp.net, dbnull

I have the following code

```
foreach (DataRowView dr in Data)
        {
            if (dr == System.DBNull.Value)
            {
                nedID = 1;
            }
        }
```

but i get the following error
Operator `==` cannot be applied to operands of type `System.Data.DataRowView` and `System.DBNull`

please can some one advice me on how i can check if the value is null or DBNULL

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to specify the field name or index.

```
foreach (DataRowView dr in Data)
{
    if (dr["nameOfField"] == System.DBNull.Value)
    {
        nedID = 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You need to replace `dr == System.DBNull.Value` with...

```
Convert.IsDBNull(dr["somefield"])
```

which returns true if it's DBNnull